# Why can I vote more than positions

Tags: feature-request, voting, election

It seems unreasonable that I can vote more number of candidates than the posts available like in recent election.

I am requesting feature request to adjust this.

It is reasonable that while voting I should only be able to vote four best that I think deserve, not all!

P.S. I don't know any election system where you can cast two votes.

Comment: I don't think N_votes $\leq$ N_positions is optimal in the mathematical theory of elections.

Comment: Well, [approval voting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approval_voting) is quite popular among some voting theorists and used by the  Mathematical Association of America.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The election is currently in the *primary* phase; the votes you are casting are to determine which candidates **reach** the actual election. Thus, there is no need to restrict votes to four candidates.

Comment: Thanks! I guess/hope there is restriction during final election.

Comment: In fact, you can only vote for your three favorite candidates in the actual election: [look at the sidebar of the "election" tab](http://math.stackexchange.com/election/4?tab=election). The voting in the actual election will use the [Meek STV method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meek's_method#Meek.27s_method).

Comment: It is actually ridiculous that you can only vote for three candidates when there are four moderator slots open. Imagine a scenario, where all the voters cast their vote for the same set of three people. :-) How will the fourth moderator be chosen then?

Comment: @user17762: I don't believe the SE election system (or STV in general) requires you to choose a full set of preferences, so just allowing four preferences to be specified wouldn't suffice, you'd have to *force* people to choose four candidates, which could influence the outcome.